# user defined function for sftp in powershell

Tags: powershell, sftp

I am able to copy file from my server to the local computer using below code.

```
sftp user@server.com:/home/abc/abc.csv ~/destination/
```

I am trying to create a PowerShell function so that I can call it by passing positional arguments.

for ex: `udf_copy abc/abc.csv ~/destination`

```
function udf_copy{
sftp user@server.com:/home/args[0] args[1]
}
```

While this copies the file abc.csv from server but saves as ~destination[0] in my home directory.

Comment: Change `sftp user@server.com:/home/args[0] args[1]` to `sftp user@server.com:/home/$($args[0]) $args[1]`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen sorry it worked as it is but when I run from my windows terminal.
udf_copy *.gz ~\destination\ it copies the file by this name in my home directory.
~destination[0]

I have updated the above question.